# Cannot see where this error is: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '10'.'

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I cannot see where the error is in the queries `sqlAction` is used for, in either the add or edit block.

Thanks in advance.

Error being thrown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '11'.'

Text visualizer shows:

```
Insert into Creditors 
Values ('asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'asdf', 'sadf', 'asdf', 'Australia', '231234', 13/10/2023 11:26:53 AM, 'Admin', 1)
```

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
    'Save addition/Changes
    'Insert/Edit A Record
    'Dim i As Integer

    Dim I1 As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim I2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim I3 As String = TextBox3.Text
    Dim I4 As String = TextBox4.Text
    Dim I5 As String = TextBox5.Text
    Dim I6 As String = TextBox6.Text
    Dim I7 As String = TextBox7.Text
    Dim I8 As String = TextBox9.Text
    Dim I9 As Date = Now()
    Dim I10 As String = strUserName
    Dim I11 As String = CheckBox1.Enabled

    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        I11 = 1
    Else
        I11 = 0
    End If

    Dim pid As Integer = TextBox8.Text

    'Stop
    If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then con.Close()

    If IsAdding = True Then

        'Stop
        con.Open()
        'Insert line into Creditors
        sqlAction = "Insert into Creditors Values ('" & I1 &
                    "','" & I2 & "', '" & I3 &
                    "', '" & I4 & "', '" & I5 & "', '" & I6 &
                    "','" & I7 & "','" & I8 & "', " & I9 & ", '" &
                    I10 & "', " & I11 & ")"
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlAction, con)

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        'MessageBox.Show("Sucessful")

        Call DefaultButtons()
        ' Stop
        LoadData(0)

    Else
        ' Stop

        'Edit Existing Record
        sqlAction = "Update Creditors Set CreditorName = '" & I1 &
                    "', Addr1 = '" & I2 & "', Addr2 = '" & I3 &
                    "', City = '" & I4 & "', State = '" & I5 &
                    "', PostCode = '" & I6 & "', Country ='" & I7 &
                    "', ContactNbr = '" & I8 &
                    "',DateAdded = " & I9 & ", AddedBy = '" & I10 & "', IsActive = " & I11 &
                    " where CreditorID = " & pid & ""
        con.Open()
        sqlCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlAction, con)

        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        LoadData(0)

        'MessageBox.Show("Sucessful")
    End If
    con.Close()
    Call TextBoxDisabled()
    IsAdding = False
    IsEditing = False
End Sub
```

Table Structure:

```
CreditorId  int False   
CreditorName    nvarchar(50)    False   
Addr1   nvarchar(50)    True    
Addr2   nvarchar(50)    True    
City    nvarchar(50)    True    
State   nvarchar(50)    True    
PostCode    nvarchar(50)    True    
Country nvarchar(50)    True    
ContactNbr  nvarchar(50)    True    
DateAdded   date    False   
AddedBy nvarchar(50)    False   
IsActive    bit False
```

Comment: A date in most if not all SQL dialects needs delimiters. E.g. in SQL Server you must use single quotes. Furthermore you should **never** build SQL strings in this way, it is asking for trouble. Use [SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter) instead.

Comment: There is no nice way to say this, but your code is _doing it wrong_ in so many ways, it's no wonder you're running into problems. Please learn how to use parameterized queries.

Comment: These couple of comments are super-important here.  Convert your SQL commands over to parameterised queries, and you'll just be able to pass the date value straight in, without having to worry about its format in a concatenated string

Comment: With your current code, if the creditor's name is O'DONOGHUE (as an example), you're going to have yourself a problem .......

Comment: Thanks Peter,Craig and Dai; no offense taken. I am 75 years old and have been out of IT for over 20 years. I used to tell programmers I hired that if they couldn't take me telling them they wrote sh*t code, then they couldn't work for me. The last time I looked at SQL was around 2000 and vb goes back to the 80's. Thanks for your help. I just got bored and decided to teach myself these 'new fangled' languages.

Comment: Some reviewers are saying that this question is a "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" because there's too much wrong with it. Maybe you could use ChatGPT or Google Bard to improve some of it by converting your SQL commands over to parameterized queries.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was not caused by a typo but rather a lack of knowledge of SQL syntax, so closing it as a typo would be a disservice. As suggested in the first comment, the immediate issue that is causing the error message you reported is the fact that you have not put your date/time literal in single quotes:

```sql
, '2023-10-13 11:26:53 AM',
```

Note the preferred, unambiguous date format too. There are numerous other ways you could improve your code but that will address that specific syntax error.